# Application of Schwarz's lemma to $f(0)=1/2$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I am trying to find the maximum of $|f'(0)|$ given $f : D(0,1)\rightarrow D(0,1)$ is analytic function such that $f(0)=1/2$. So if $T_{\alpha}=\dfrac{z-\alpha}{1-\overline{\alpha}z}$, I considered $g(z)=T_{1/2}\circ f(z)$. Then $g(0)=0$ and $|g(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z$ in unit disk. With this I got $|f(z)|\leq |T_{-1/2}(z)|$. But then if I use directly $g'$ and calculate the derivative, I got $|f'(0)|\leq \frac{9}{8}$ but if I use previous inequality of $|f(z)|$, I got the upper bound for $|f'(0)|$ is $\frac{3}{2}$. Which one is correct (is $\frac{9}{8}$ actually the sharpest bound)? If $\frac{9}8$ is the sharpest one, what is example of $f$ that achieves the bound?

Comment: @MartinR so for $9/8$, I use $|g'(0)|\leq 1$. $g'(0)=T'_{1/2}(f(0))f'(0)$. Now with this I got $T'_{1/2}(1/2)=8/9$ so $|f'(0)|\leq 9/8$. For $3/2$ I used $|f(z)|\leq |T_{-1/2}(z)|$ and calculate the derivatives of both functions iside absolute values. How did you get $3/4$?

Comment: You cannot take the derivatives on both sides of an inequality, $|f(z)|\leq |T_{-1/2}(z)|$ does not imply $|f'(z)|\leq |T_{-1/2}'(z)|$.

Comment: $T'_{1/2}(1/2)=8/9$ is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR ah I just realised my mistake in calculation, thank you.

Comment: @MartinR yes I knew I cannot take derivatives inside absolute values, but since my calculation was wrong  I tried another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that $g(z)=T_{1/2}\circ f(z)$ satisfies the conditions of the Schwarz lemma, so that $|g'(0)| \le 1$. Since
$$
T_{1/2}'(z) = \frac{3/4}{(1-z/2)^2}
$$
and
$$
 g'(0) = T_{1/2}'(f(0)) f'(0) = T_{1/2}'\left(\frac 12\right) f'(0)
= \frac 43 f'(0)
$$
it follows that
$$|f'(0)| = \frac 34 |g'(0)| \le \frac 34 \, .
$$
This bound is sharp, as can be seen by choosing $f = T_{1/2}^{-1} = T_{-1/2}$.

One can also use the [Schwarz-Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz%E2%80%93Pick_theorem):
$$
 {\frac  {\left|f'(z)\right|}{1-\left|f(z)\right|^{2}}}\leq {\frac  {1}{1-\left|z\right|^{2}}}.
$$
with $z = 0$, $f(0) = 1/2$.

Comment: Inches away from six figures, and boy have you deserved it!

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer: Thank you.